# updates to the operating system

Tags: updates, system

Excellencies
I really like your operating system for its simplicity and appearance.
I'm a fan of elementary operating systems, but I had three headaches.

All due to updates to the operating system, it was on three occasions that I was without the operating system.
I had to install all over again, losing the saved data.

Today, October 11, 2019, I made an update and ran out of system, what happens is as follows:
The PC starts and has the cursor in the upper left corner and you're done, it doesn't do anything else, it gets the black screen, and it doesn't boot ...

Thanks for letting me know how to remedy the situation.
This message was written with CD Live because I have no operating system.

Cordial greetings,
Joaquim

Comment: Do you have your bios set to boot from the ssd/hdd you installed to os on?
Also dont understand what you mean by ran out of system?

Comment: Do you have dualboot? Or elementaryOS only? Do you use UEFI (Secure boot)?

Comment: Also, if you don't manage to repair the boot, you can at least backup all of your data from the Live CD.